# How does compiler know which function I want to use?

Tags: objective-c

I defined two functions.They are all the same, except in different class. And I imported one class into another class, and then used @selector(functionName).How does compiler know which function I want to use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the functions are the same then it doesn't matter. At runtime is decided which method is called.

Comment: Post your code as text in the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "selector" is the *name* of a function. The type is `SEL`, which is no more than a typedef to `NSString*`. The selector not the function implementation itself (which also exists, type `IMP`).

Therefore, you cannot execute a selector, because there is no code behind.

If you want to "call" a function thru a selector, you need to specify an instance on which you want the selector to be performed onto. The root class `NSObject` has several functions like `performSelector`, which will take the selector, look for the implementation in that object, and then execute that function implementation.

The magic behind is the Objective C runtime. In reality, it's a little more sophisticated than explained above; look for `objc_msgSend` if you are interested in more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering.